# How to add command+a on a JTextfield?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, key-bindings, keystroke

Hello I'm trying to add the select-all, cut, copy and paste command in my application, I managed to work out the cut, copy and paste command but I don't seem to have figured out how to add the <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> command...

this worked for my <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> command

```
text.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()),  "cut");
```

but when I try this for <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>:

```
text.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()),  "select");
```

it doesn't seem to work...

I read something about using this void to select the text, but I don't know how to bind it to the command+a command

```
  myTextfield.selectAll();
```

Anyone got an idea on how to correctly implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the correct `String`: `"select-all"` instead of `"select"`.

You can discover these `String`s by investigating the `InputMap`, for example by using:

```
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        InputMap inputMap = textField.getInputMap( JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED );
        KeyStroke[] keyStrokes = inputMap.allKeys();
        for ( int i = 0; i < keyStrokes.length; i++ ) {
          KeyStroke keyStroke = keyStrokes[ i ];
          Object value = inputMap.get( keyStroke );
          System.out.println(keyStroke + "-\"" + value + "\"");
        }
      }
    } );
  }
```

which prints out (not the complete output pasted here)

```
ctrl pressed BACK_SPACE-"delete-previous-word"
ctrl pressed A-"select-all"
shift pressed KP_RIGHT-"selection-forward"
```

This shows the `String` you are looking for is `"select-all"`.

Note that it might be really counter-intuitive for a user to switch the function of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key . For example on a Mac the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> by default does select all (which is expected), but I would never expect that on a Windows/Linux machine

Comment: thank you! Ill keep it in mind, and ill put that snippet in my Misc.java, so I can use it more often :)